# I need to select data from a table according to time.But my table field is datetime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to select data from a table according to time.But my table field is datetime.How can i select data from table only depending on time?Can i use only time in where clause?Please reply

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      Col1 INT
    , Col2 DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @temp (Col1, Col2)
VALUES 
    (1, '2013-08-29 07:41:43.717'),
    (2, '2013-08-29 08:41:50.067')

SELECT * 
FROM @temp
WHERE CAST(Col2 AS TIME) BETWEEN '08:00' AND '12:00'
```

Output -

```
Col1        Col2
----------- -----------------------
2           2013-08-29 08:41:50.067
```

Comment: I have an another problem.Here i have two scenarios.1)

Comment: I have an another problem.Here i have two scenarios.1) I want to see in the month of February datas  between 13.00 and 17.00.2) I want to see in the month of February datas  from 20:00 to 08:00 the next morning.For the fist scenario its suitable.How can i select data for second scenario?Please reply

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME, column) FROM table
```

column is your datetime column

You can also use CONVERT(TIME, column) in your WHERE-clause.